# is there a way to use SPDY with the google cloud storage objective c api?

Tags: objective-c, google-cloud-storage

I would like to use SPDY with the google cloud storage objective c API. Is there a way to do this? I'm digging into the SPDY for iPhone code, but having difficulty getting openssl built and I hear that the Chrome browser for iOS is using SPDY. Perhaps there is an easier/better way to do this?

Comment: Google Cloud Storage definitely supports SPDY. I'm not sure about the best way to create a SPDY connection with Objective C though.

Comment: Thanks. I have not found a Google-supported way to do this.. May have to wait for next version of HTTP.

Answer (score 0):

Google Cloud Storage supports SPDY. Therefore you can use any general purpose objective-c SPDY library to talk to Google Cloud Storage at https://storage.googleapis.com.

I have no experience with any objective-c SPDY libraries, but the top result for objective-c spdy is the following project on github: https://github.com/sorced-jim/SPDY-for-iPhone

Comment: Yes.. Gave it a try a while back and it built with a custom Ssl (you can't use the default ios one).